# jQuery - remove all matching ids

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove all matching IDs `#mce_*`,

But my below code is not working:

```
    jQuery('[id*="mce_"]').attr('id', function(i, c) {
      return c.match(/mce_\d+/g).join(" ");
    });
```

Comment: I believe you want to use `[id^=mce_]`

Comment: please tell me the difference between `*` and `^`

Comment: `*` contains, whereas `^` starts with.

Comment: look at the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) docs

Comment: @HowToPlease Check here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ . So: `*-` (contains): http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ and `^=` (starts with): http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$('[id^="mce_"]').removeAttr('id')
```

Comment: Thanks, short and simple

Comment: If my answer could help you, you can validate it.

Answer (score 4):

use this code:

```
$('[id^=mce_]').removeAttr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

*Updated (`^` and `removeAttr`)

If you want to remove `id` Try this

```
jQuery('[id^="mce_"]').removeAttr('id');
```

If you want to remove elements Try this

```
jQuery('[id^="mce_"]').remove();
```